# Next.js Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a SSR React App for the first time, I should transform previous CSR App into SSR for better SEO optimization, but I'm getting error with React UseState.

I would appreciate any suggestion for how to transform CSR App into SSR, since I'm working with it for the first time

This is my code:

```
    import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

// Components
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation_Com";
import Navigation_Com_Two from "../components/Navigation_Com_Two";

// Styles
// import styles from "../styles/main-screen-styles/main_screen.css";

// Assets
import photo from "../assets/main-man.png";
import arrow from "../assets/main_arrow.svg";
import phoneMan from "../assets/main-man-phone.png";

import muscle_icon from "../assets/muscle_up.svg";
import lightning from "../assets/lightning.svg";
import delivery_icon from "../assets/delivery-icon.svg";
import anti_pills from "../assets/anti-pills.svg";
import protection from "../assets/protection.svg";

// Icons
import { FaTelegramPlane } from "react-icons/fa";

// Fonts
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

// Icons
import { FaPhone } from "react-icons/fa";

// Translation
import { useTranslation, Trans } from "react-i18next";

// Popup
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

// Email JS
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";
import { Bounce } from "react-reveal";

const MainScreen = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const closeModal = () => setOpen(false);

  const [windowOpen, setWindowOpen] = useState(false);
  const closeWindow = () => setWindowOpen(false);

  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");

  const form = useRef();

  function handleClick() {
    setOpen((o) => !o);
  }

  function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPhoneNumber("");
    setOpen((o) => !o);
    navigate("/thanks");
    // setWindowOpen((o) => !o);
  }

  return (<div></div>);}
```